# Play is sometimes very slow and other times it's very fast in After effects. Why?

Tags: after-effects

I've just installed after effects and I would like to learn it.

When I click the play button, it seems like it starts to render so the frame rate is very low ( one frame per many seconds) and the the whole interface is laggy.

After rendering few frames, I don't remember what I really did but I clicked the play button again and the video was played smoothly.

I clicked the play button again and it became laggy one more time.

I think the preview process should be different from the rendering process in After Effects (just like 3D max or any other similar software. There is a 3D view port that doesn't render the exact materials and lighting). The two processes are separated to make the play/pauses fast.

I would like to know how do people use after effects with this mixed (Rendering & Preview) processes? Of course, I know that there is a method to get around it and I'm missing it. I would appreciate it if you give it to me.